# Structure of logic in Symfony app

Tags: php, symfony, architecture

I am quiet new to the symfony framework and for a new project, I want to make sure I got a correct setup. The project itself will have a frontend and backend and will contain several modules like Blog, Forum, News articles etc.

Every module will become a bundle. That looks like the best solution to us. We want to be able to take out a bundle and replace it with a different bundle. So for instance, it could be possible that we have 2 different kind of blog bundles which we can swap if we need. So it's very important that all settings and other parts related to the module are in the same bundle.

Now, the problem will be that the settings of every module, will be across different pages. Like for example the sorting order of comments on a Blog and Forum, will be configured on the same page, away from the pages where you manage your blog articles. The uploads settings for every module will be on a different page. etc.

To me, it sounds most logical that, somehow, these settings are updated on the specified blog and forum bundle. So all parts are together. Or maybe that somehow, the page responsible for the settings, is able to find which modules have these kind of settings and retrieve.

What's the best architecture to solve this problem?

-- EDIT --

Blog articles, blog comments, blog uploads, it's all part of one blog bundle. The settings of the blog bundle won't appear in the forum bundle neither. What I mean is that there is a seperate page from the bundles called "settings" which takes care of all settings of the application. It also should take care of settings per bundle. So you can edit the blog settings and forum settings on the same page and this page is not a part of any forum or blog bundle.

Answer (score 0):

To have a bundle for the blog : OK, to have a bundle for blog articles and an other one for the comments that's very very bad. So, you can create a setting page for your bundle of course, and you can have the core of your application who is creating the links between each of this pages.

But if you need settings on your page which is on different bundles, your application has a bad structure. To a functionality, use services, to a set of functionality which are linked together, use a bundle.

---- EDIT
Your bundles have to have a setting page in his its own bundle. You can add them easily with twig but you will always need to do this template yourself (and that's normal) to create your setting's page. If you have a parameter used by more than one bundle, you can just register this parameter in the same place and cut your template to have a block for each parameter, and just include the one you need on your full template.

But that's weird, in my opinion, one setting page per bundle is a good way, and redundant parameter is bad, because today you want the same setting to sort the comments for blog and forum, but tomorrow, perhaps you would like to have a difference between them.

That's my point of view, not the "solution" ;)

Comment: I am not creating seperate bundles for each part. Blog is one bundle and contains the articles and comments.

Let me edit my post to explain it a bit more